# How to send events directly from Phoenix Live View to a component

Tags: elixir, phoenix-live-view

I have a question about the Phoenix LiveView Component (v0.15.4).

In the documentation, there is an example code:

```
def handle_info({:updated_card, card}, socket) do
  send_update CardComponent, id: card.id, board_id: socket.assigns.id
  {:noreply, socket}
end
```

LiveView components do not have a `handle_info/2` callback, so `send_update/3` is called to redirect events from the parent LiveView to a specific component.

However, I want to send events directly from the parent LiveView to the specific component, because I want to do something like this

```
# parent LiveView
def handle_info({:new_card, card_id}, socket) do
  send_event CardStackComponent, id: :card_stack, event: "add_card", params: %{"card_id" => card_id}
  {:noreply, socket}
end

# component
def handle_event("add_card", %{"card_id" => card_id} = _params, socket) do
  card = get_card(card_id)

  socket =
    update(socket, :cards, fn cards ->)
      [card | cards]     
    end)
    
  {:noreply, socket}
end
```

Of course, there is no such function as `Phoenix.LiveView.send_event/2`. The above is a fictional code to illustrate my intention.

I know how to send events from a client (browser) to a specific component, either by adding the `phx-target="<%= @myself %>"` attribute to an HTML element, or by using the `pushEventTo` method in a JavaScript program.

However, as far as I know, there is no way to send an event directly from a parent LiveView to a specific component.

Is there any workaround or better way?

Comment: I would recommend to stick to the standard way of passing updates to components, however you could always use PubSub and pass the events there.

Answer (score 1):

[Phoenix Pubsub](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_pubsub/Phoenix.PubSub.html) is the answer.

```
defmodule QuickPick.Cards.LiveUpdates do
  @topic inspect(__MODULE__)

  @doc "subscribe for all cards"
  def subscribe_live_view do
    Phoenix.PubSub.subscribe(QuickPick.PubSub, topic(), link: true)
  end

  @doc "subscribe for specific card"
  def subscribe_live_view(card_id) do
    Phoenix.PubSub.subscribe(QuickPick.PubSub, topic(card_id), link: true)
  end

  @doc "notify for all cards"
  def notify_live_view(message) do
    Phoenix.PubSub.broadcast(QuickPick.PubSub, topic(), message)
  end

  @doc "notify for specific card"
  def notify_live_view(card_id, message) do
    Phoenix.PubSub.broadcast(QuickPick.PubSub, topic(card_id), message)
  end

  defp topic, do: @topic
  defp topic(card_id), do: topic() <> to_string(card_id)
end
```

Subscribe and handle on updating

```
def mount(session, socket) do
  LiveUpdates.subscribe_live_view(card.id)
  ...
end

def handle_info({_requesting_module, [:recommendations, :updated], []}, socket) do
  ...
end
```

Updating

```
LiveUpdates.notify_live_view(
  card.id,
  {__MODULE__, [:recommendations, :updated], []}
)
```

Comment: I guess it won't work, as the components are not running under their own process but under LiveView's pid. So, it's the parent LiveView that will receive all pubsub messages

Answer (score 0):

you can also do

```
# parent LiveView
def handle_info({:new_card, card_id}, socket) do
  send_update CardStackComponent, id: :card_stack, card_id: card_id
  {:noreply, socket}
end

#component
def update(%{card_id: card_id} = _assigns, socket) do
  card = get_card(card_id)

  socket =
    update(socket, :cards, fn cards ->
      [card | cards]     
    end)
  {:ok, socket}
end
```

you have to have in mind that `update/2` is going to be called on each render. More info about this [here](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveComponent.html#module-life-cycle)

Is also worth mention that you may want to maintain the state either in the LiveView or the LiveComponent but not both, as is mentioned [here](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveComponent.html#module-managing-state)